# Javascript form submission onclick not working in Google Chrome

Tags: php, javascript, forms

I am trying to submit a form onclick of an anchor. Here is the code:

```
function submitLink() {
    document.forms["background-form"].submit();
    return false;
}
```

This code works in FF and IE but not in Chrome. Anyone know why? I am calling the function like so:

```
<a href="<?php echo "background.php?cred=".$cred['id']; ?>" onclick="submitLink();">Remove</a>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return false from the onclick function to prevent the default action.
Otherwise you will just follow the link.

Try it like this

```
<a href="<?php echo "background.php?cred=".$cred['id']; ?>" onclick="return submitLink();">Remove</a>
```

I should also note that your link isn't an anchor link, an anchor link needs to have a [fragmentation identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier). your link is just a link, that upon clicked, will cause the browser to navigate to it by means of a http get request, causing the current page to unload.

However it would be, much, better to bind the event handler trough jQuery, and use the built in preventDefault functionality.

Read more about it here

http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Thanks very much Willem. Now the issue is that it submits the form without going to that anchor link. Any way around this without altering the form action to redirect? Just wanted data to post and then the link to be followed.

Comment: yes that because your link isn't an anchor link, i edited my answer to clarify

Comment: There is a use for prefering this method to jquery. If the string was generated by some javascript code long after the page has loaded, jquery callbacks in the `$(document).ready` function will not work...

Answer (score 0):

If you have found that `onClick` event does not work on Google Chrome, then here is quick way to fix it:

Replace `onclick` form id with its name, For example, let’s say you have the following:

```
<form id="form1" name="checkform1"
```

Find JS event:

```
onclick="document.form1.cSSld.value=''"
```

Replace with:

```
onclick="document.checkform1.cSSld.value=''"
```

All set. It now works with all web browsers.